# Understanding the weighted Polya's Enumeration Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Setup:

Let $Y^X$ be the set of all functions from X to Y. An action of $\phi$ of $G$ on $X$ induces a natural group action $\phi'$ of $G$ on $Y^X$ by $\phi'(g,f) \to f'=f \circ p_g^{-1}$. Here $p_g$ is the permutation induced from action of $g \in G$ to $X$.

So if we think of $Y^X$ as a coloring of point in $X$ by colors in $Y$, then the action of $g$ on $X^Y$ sends a coloring $f$  to a coloring $f'$ where $f'$ maps the preimage of $x\in X$ to the color $f(x)$.

Let $p$ be a permutation of elements in $X$, then the type of $p$ is $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ where $b_i$ is the number of circle of length $i$ in the cycle decomposition of $p$.

The cycle index polynomial of a group action $\phi$ is defined as $$Z_{\phi}(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{b_i(g)}$$ where $b_i(g)$ is the ith element of the type of the implied pemutation on $X$ induced by $g$.

A configuration is an orbit of action of $G$ on $Y^X$.

If $w:Y \to \mathbf{R}$ is a weight assignment to each element in $Y$, then we define $W(f)= \prod_{x\in X} w(f(x))$. Namely, we take product of all weight of the colors asigned to each elements in $X$.

The Configuration Generating Function(CGF) is defined as $F(C)=\sum_{c \in C}W(c)$. WHere $C$ is the set of all configurations.

So finally the theorem that I'm interested is due to  Polya,

Let $G$ be a group and $X,Y$ be finite sets, where $|X|=n$. Let $w$ be a weight function on $Y$. The for any group action $\phi$ of $G$ on $X$, then the configuration generating function  is given by  $$Z_{\phi}(\sum_{y\in Y} w(y), \sum_{y\in Y} w(y)^2,...,\sum_{y\in Y} w(y)^n)$$

Comment: yes thanks for the help!

Comment: Generally speaking, accepting answers quickly is bad because you lose the chance to get another good answer, an answer that looks at it from another point of a wiev.

Comment: Wikipedia has the [proof by Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Proof_of_theorem).

Comment: @User2020201 i mean, you're just factually wrong. i have offered bounties before, and, every time, I've awarded the bounty right when a complete answer was posted